# Warnings for calling UIPanGestureRecognizer touchesBegan from subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In a custom subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer, when I override touchesBegan with:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self view].superview bringSubviewToFront:[self view]];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The super line gets the warnings:

```
....warning: 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' may not respond to '-touchesBegan:withEvent:'
... Semantic Issue: 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' may not respond to 'touchesBegan:withEvent:'
```

Why is this?

The initial attempt at fixing this was by importing 'UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h' as per the UIGestureRecognizer docs for subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer, but I get a 'No such file or directory' error when I try that.

I've got UIKit.framework included, and tried adding

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

but it doesn't work either.

Did I forget something?

Comment: including the file won't prevent the warnings for the instruction you show i think, could you tell us what is actually the warning you get ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need :

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

Also, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) is a guide about event progamming in iOS, which contains instructions in order to write a gesture recognizer subclass.

Comment: Ah, that's what I needed. I didn't realise I needed to include the 'UIKit/' prefix. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this!  I missed the need to include that header if I subclass the gesture recognizers.  This saved me!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explicitly import that file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

From [UIGestureRecognizer Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You may create a subclass that UIGestureRecognizer that recognizes a distinctive gesture—for example, a “check mark” gesture. If you are going to create such a concrete gesture recognizer, be sure to import the UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h header file. This header declares all the methods and properties a subclass must either override, call, or reset.